# Flutter android app crash after a while of manipulation

Tags: flutter

my android app crash after about 5min of working fine, with no reason.
I trayed to figure out what could be the problem but no clue.
some help will be great.

I've got this on the console:

```
W/s.myname.MyApp(14516): Accessing hidden method Lcom/msic/qarth/PatchStore;- 
>createDisableExceptionQarthFile(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Z (blacklist, JNI)
E/s.myname.MyApp(14516): [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime(14516): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-14
E/AndroidRuntime(14516): Process: yas.myname.MyAppName, PID: 14516
E/AndroidRuntime(14516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed 
on the main thread. Current thread: Timer-14
E/AndroidRuntime(14516):    at 
io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureRunningOnMainThread(FlutterJNI.java:992)
E/AndroidRuntime(14516):    at 
io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.invokePlatformMessageResponseCallback(FlutterJNI.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(14516):    at 
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(14516):    at 
io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:238)
E/AndroidRuntime(14516):    at 
com.anish.trust_fall.TrustFallPlugin$1.gotLocation(TrustFallPlugin.java:43)
E/AndroidRuntime(14516):    at 
com.anish.trust_fall.MockLocation.MockLocationCheck$GetLastLocation.run(MockLocationCheck.java:90)
E/AndroidRuntime(14516):    at java.util.TimerThread.processTask(Timer.java:569)
E/AndroidRuntime(14516):    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:527)
E/AndroidRuntime(14516):    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(14516): stop checker.
I/Process (14516): Sending signal. PID: 14516 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: You are using a library that calls flutter code from.a different thread/service. In android you should run all methodCalls to flutter from.a uiThread. That or you are doing something weird with a timer. It's difficult to tell since i don't know your pubspec.yaml

Comment: @ValdaXD
i use no timer, but maybe one of my dependencies do.

    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  vibration: 1.2.4
  audioplayers: ^0.15.1
  assets_audio_player: ^1.7.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3
  geolocator: ^5.3.2+2
  permission: ^0.1.7
  location: ^3.0.2
  location_permissions: ^3.0.0
  trust_fall: ^1.0.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.28+1
  search_map_place: ^0.3.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^0.2.1
  google_map_polyline: ^0.2.0+1
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.4.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why poeple find error reports so hard to read. The problem is your trust_fall library. It's clearly stated in

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14516):    at 
com.anish.trust_fall.TrustFallPlugin$1.gotLocation(TrustFallPlugin.java:43)
```

A quick search and the problem is [already reported](https://github.com/anish-adm/trust_fall/issues/4) and not solved.